# Ubuntu 17.10 Android MTP Issue

Tags: usb, nautilus, 17.10, android, mtp

I tried few of solutions but nothing worked for me.
I am on Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME. 
I get following in lsusb,

> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b05:5600 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.

But nautilus doesn't show anything. I am unable to access my Android device on my laptop. Android device is having Android 7.1.2. Audio routing is also not working.

Edit: I have also done editing this file (/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules) and filled the vendor and product ID, but no use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I have a HTC U11.  It mounts fine on my laptop with 16.04 but not on my other laptop 17.10.  I notice on 17.10 the /etc/udev/rules.d folder is completely empty.

```
~$ mtp-detect 
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=0bb4 and PID=0c93) is a HTC EVO 4G LTE/One V (ID1).
   Found 1 device(s):
   HTC: EVO 4G LTE/One V (ID1) (0bb4:0c93) @ bus 1, dev 12
Attempting to connect device(s)
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
```

I put the phone into Developer mode and turned on USB Debugging and that got mtp-detect to go a little further:

```
~$ mtp-detect 
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=0bb4 and PID=0f87) is a HTC HTC One (MTP+ADB+?).
   Found 1 device(s):
   HTC: HTC One (MTP+ADB+?) (0bb4:0f87) @ bus 1, dev 15
Attempting to connect device(s)
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device

LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

But it still won't connect.

Edit:
My issue turned out to be that Calibre was running (ebook reader) and trying to hijack management of my phone.  If I kill Calibre I can connect with no issues.